# Database wide table or referenced table with record type

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to represent a vehicle (think car or truck) in a database. I have up to 62 pieces of information I'd like to store for each. Examples: year, make, model, drive type, brake system, Mfr. body code, steering type, wheel base, etc. The information are Ids which reference a 3rd party database which provides the labels for each Id. The provider has 1 table to list all makes, 1 table to list all "Steering types", etc.

All vehicles will populate the year, make, and model columns. Almost no record (if any) will populate more than 10 columns. But if I looked at all vehicles, then every column would be used by at least one record.

One approach would be to have a single table that has 62 columns. Again most records will have NULL values in most columns.

Alternatively I can do something like this (ignoring indices and primary key for sake of example):

```
create table vehicles (
  id identity(1,1) int,
  year int,
  make int,
  model int
)

create table constraints (
  id identity(1,1) int,
  vehicleId int, -- foreign key to vehicles.id
  constraintTypeId int, -- foreign key to constraintTypes.id
  value int
)

create table constraintTypes (
  id identity(1,1) int,
  name nvarchar(200) -- Example: "wheel base", "brake system" etc
)
```

With this second method if a vehicle only stores 2 pieces of information (aside from year, make, model), then it would have 2 records in table constraints.

Users wish to have a page to view all applications. If I have a table with 62 columns I'd need 62 joins in the query to get the labels. I could store labels on the vehicle to make retrieval faster, but than when labels change in the source data it might be slow to update my vehicles table.

At current there are over 12 million vehicle records, and the source data changes monthly (additions, deletes, and a few label changes).

Is it better a better design to have more columns, even if most are always just NULL. Or is the second approach better? How does one even calculate the best approach? Even if I had 62 columns they are all valid to every vehicle, but for cataloging purposes most are left empty. For example if a record should match any "1999 Dodge Viper" (regardless of steering type, or body style, etc) the user doesn't want to have to populate all 62 columns, they want to just see one record for "1999 Dodge Viper".

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a specific case of the general issue related to data anomalys and normalisation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

And there is no 'right' answer although experience suggests there are 'better' and 'worse' answers. So a question to help you with your planning.

- Will the requirements ever change? E.g. will someone one day want to
  record the brake shoe type, or drivers seat type? If yes what are the
  implications of your 62 column    table becoming a 63 (or 99) column
  table. (In my mind this leads me towards your second method)

Also remember thanks to Views the presentation of the data, even in the DB, does not have to match it storage.  E.g. you can have well normalised tables and a view to show users 62 (or 63 or 99) columns.

Comment: The number of columns relies upon an industry standard which in the last 6 years hasn't changed. I understand your point about the change though. If I used the second method, and wanted the View to match the first method, that would be a query with 59 joins. I assume much more than 5 or 6 joins is considered rather excessive?

Comment: You haven't actually tried googling for "turning a table on its side" yourself have you? ;)

Comment: Naturally before writing that I checked it gave the expected result.  Also when using an RDBMS I am less familiar with I google the same thing.

Comment: The first few results I get are regarding Excel. It's a similar effect, but they doen't speak of the efficiency of doing the same thing in MSSQL. I'm not asking how to do it (I gave the schema to do it), I'm asking if it's wise to do under my particular circumstance.